# Informatica Powercenter 9.6.1 pmcmd Fatal Error

Tags: unix, informatica

I am trying to run workflow using `pmcmd` in `ksh` and I am getting below error.

> ld.so.1: pmcmd: fatal: libpmasrt.so: open failed: No such file or directory
>   startwf.ksh[18]: 7489 Killed

`PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment paths are already set.

Any help please.

Comment: what paths are set in PATH variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set and export PATH with the server bin directory in it:

```
export PATH=/opt/PowerCenter/server/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have done this and this seems to be the solution. But it is not working for me. Thanks.